# Managing AT Commands for SIM COM A7672S SIM Module - Header Appending Issue

Tags: header, at-commands, simcom

I'm currently working with the SIM COM A7672S SIM module to download a file in chunks from an Amazon S3 server.

I am using the AT command '**AT+HTTPPARA="USERDATA","Range: bytes=0-1023"**' followed by '**AT+HTTPACTION=0**' for the GET request and then using '**AT+HTTPREAD**' to read and store the data. This process is implemented in a while loop until the entire file is downloaded.

I am encountering an issue when setting the header for the second time. The header seems to be appended, resulting in a format like '**Range:
bytes=0-1023,bytes=1024-2047**' instead of the desired '**Range: bytes=1024-2047**'. Unfortunately, there's no direct option to delete a header and reconfigure it without terminating the HTTP request and setting up a new one.

I'm seeking advice from the community on whether there's a smart workaround to manage headers effectively without terminating the HTTP request in the SIM A7672S SIM module.